# Operating on the values of a data frame

Tags: r

I need to convert the values of some columns of a dataframe to numeric and then compute the difference with the previous value. I used the following method (Chg is te dataframe):

```
Chg[,c(3,4,6:13)]<-sapply(Chg[,c(3,4,6:13)],FUN=function(x)log(as.numeric(x)))
Chg[,c(3,4,6:13)]<-sapply(Chg[,c(3,4,6:14)],FUN=function(x)(x /lag(x) - 1))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't recycle `sapply(Chg[, c(3, 4, 6:14)], FUN = function(x) (x/lag(x) - 1))` (size 11) to size 10.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to show your `dataframe` as well for someone to understand what the problem is.

Comment: `lag` shortens `x` by one. You need to define a starting (or ending?) value. Take a look at `x <- 1:10` and compare `x` and `lag(x)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
for(i in c(3,4,6:13)){
  Chg[,i] = log(as.numeric(Chg[,i]))
  b = as.numeric(Chg[,1])[1] #deletable
  Chg[,i] =  Chg[,i]/lag( Chg[,i])-1
  Chg[1,i]=b #deletable
}
```

I assumed that the first value will be unchanged si I saved in `b`to reput it after, but if you want to keep the `NA`, you can delete these two step